# What does the guard rune in Quake-Live do exactly?

Tags: quake-live

It has been suggested to use the Guard rune to combat people using rail and the Doubler rune. What does it do exactly?

Comment: Tough question, I don't think this is documented anywhere and, well, "pros" just frown on runes and everything related to them. At any rate it should offer damage reduction. I doubt it's high enough to completely offset Doubler... we'd need to do _science._)

Comment: @badp I don't see how pros can frown on runes when so many seem to rely on doubler.

Comment: They just don't seem to play these CTF maps...

Comment: no worries, I got somebody else to plummet grenades onto me. See the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<s>For now I'll reference [this holysh1t article](http://www.holysh1t.net/quake-live-ctf-beginner-tutorial/), citing damage taken being halved. I suppose there's more to it than that, especially regarding armor (which seems more effective with the rune.)</s>

---

I and that good brony of a [Tristan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/14775/tristan) have done a little bit of science, and it turns out holysh1t got it wrong. That's just how much people at the highest levels care about maps with runes. Anyway!

#### Getting hit with 100/100 (= 100 hitpoints, 100 armor) by a direct grenade hit:

```
YOU              THEM  Without doubler      With doubler
Without guard             66/34 (-100)       49/1 (-150)
With guard                83/34 ( -83)       75/1 (-124)
```

#### Getting hit with 200/0 by a direct grenade hit:

```
YOU              THEM  Without doubler      With doubler
Without guard            100/0  (-100)       50/0 (-150)
With guard               150/0  ( -50)      125/0 ( -75)
```

We also tried with one hit from a plasma gun (20/30 damage) and the results are consistent with the above.

**Guard halves damage taken by your hitpoints *after* your armor absorbed damage normally.**

From what I recall, armor soaks two damage points every three. Now, with guard every second hitpoint damage is skipped.

This means that:

- You get one sixth less damage (**-17%**) so long as you have armor to absorb damage.
- You get half damage (**-50%**) when you do not have armor.

Considered that doubler appears to be a flat +50% damage boost, this means guard actually has the edge over doubler, although in this match up the guard player's armor *will* evaporate real fast.

(Oh, another thing. Scout does *not* make you get more damage than normal.)